# SQL: extracting MON-YEAR from date

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to receive output as "01-FEB-11" from `sysdate`(or say, at any day in JUN-12).

Answer (score 1):

```
select TO_CHAR(sysdate,'DD-MON-YY') from dual
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be 'DD-MON-YY' if the OP wants the month in uppercase?

Comment: First ..I want that in "Date" formate...and the question is i want to get date ie 13 month older than sysdate...

Comment: @user1452037: no, your question was "extracting MON-YEAR from date... I want to receive output as "01-FEB-11" from sysdate". In other words,  you want the date displayed in a particular format. You never said anything about "13 months older than sysdate".